# php header Content-disposition

Tags: php

I have a very basic question illustrated by the code snippet below.
This is the relevant part of a much bigger program in which I wish to download a zip file. The code as shown, with the comments in place, produce the expected browser output "Download the file now."

When I un-comment the code, the zip file is correctly downloaded to my browser!

However, the browser output is not produced. How do I regain control? I would like for the user to then have other options. (By the way, un-commenting the single "Content-disposition" line is sufficient to cause the loss of control.)

I have tried including the code, putting it in a function, many possible combinations of ob_start, ob_end flush, etc., all to no avail. I am sure I am overlooking something very fundamental and would appreciate some suggestions.

Thanks.

```
<?php
$sZipFN = 'file.zip';
// header("Content-type: application/zip");
// header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$sZipFN");
// readfile($sZipFN);
$sMsg = "Download the file now.";        
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <p> <?php echo $sMsg; ?> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Each URL can carry only one resource. It's either a ZIP file, or a HTML page. Not both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP won't show page and download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894891/php-wont-show-page-and-download)

Answer (score 1):

You can't - you have to redirect to the options page and then start the download via javascript redirect (`document.location = 'http://download.url/';`)

This will start the download and leave the user on the options page like you desire.

Don't forget to include a 'Click here if the download fails to start' link somewhere near the top of the page (just in case javascript is disabled)